# Cannot run nodejs script in command prompt

Tags: javascript, node.js

When I try to run a `node.js` program in Windows command prompt by stating its location, it will invariably say:

> [stated location] is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

In all answers to similar questions, in all `node.js` manuals, it is assumed you can just run a `node.js` file by calling it from its location. There will always be the suggestion of trying some `hello world` example BEFORE establishing a server and so on.

Even if I clean the command prompt with `prompt $ cmd`, and then write the whole location manually, I get the same message.

When I run

```
echo %path%
```

I get `C:\Program Files\nodejs\bin`

When I run

```
node -v
```

I get `v6.10.3`

When I run

```
node a00.js
```

(where `a00.js` is the script's name), it believes the whole path is a module, so it says it `cannot recognize that module`.

If I clear the command prompt with `prompt $ cmd` and then run `node a00.js`, it believes `a00.js` to be a module, so it says it `cannot recognize that module`.

Comment: Have you tried use cmder? http://cmder.net/

Comment: `When I run "echo %path%" I get "C:\Program Files\nodejs\bin"` Shouldn't you be in the directory where `a00.js` is? Then if you run `node a00.js` it should work.

Comment: Well, a00.js is in nodejs, which is in Program Files, which in turn is in C...

So I believe I am in the directory where a00.js is, I am not?

I will try cmder, thanks. I do not know what a cmd emulator is, or how it could help, but I will explore it.

Comment: @Algunillo If you have `a00.js` inside the bin directory then yes, it will find a00.js and execute it. But more than likely that `js` file is in your project folder which probably won't be saved inside the nodeJs bin directory. So switch path first to the location of the js file then run `node a00.js`

Comment: Well, I type "C:\Program Files\nodejs\a00.js". That is the path to the file, but it tells me "'Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command, etc."

Comment: @Algunillo Quick tip, if you reply to someone make sure to do `@name` it will notify that person that a message was received. :)

Comment: @Edilson Borges Thank you for the tip. Just learning how to behave here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your path knows where `node.js` is, but it does not know where a00.js is. So you need to run the command as `node` followed by the path to file. (copy all commands including the double quotes)

```
node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\a00.js"
```

As an example, try this.

create a file called `hello.js` save it in `C:\Windows\Temp\` (or where you prefer)

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(1337, "127.0.0.1");
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:1337/');
```

now open `cmd` and run it like this (assuming you saved it in `C:\Windows\Temp\`

```
node "c:\Windows\Temp\hello.js"
```

if you run it from path, meaning you `CD` to the directory where the a00.js file exists, then only can you run it as `node a00.js

as an example, assuming `a00.js` exists in `C:\Windows\Temp`:

```
cd c:\Windows\Temp
node a00.js
```

**Important note** when using any path, always enclose it in double quotes.

This will cause errors:

```
node C:\Program Files\test\a00.js
```

This will work:

```
node "C:\Program Files\test\a00.js"
```

Comment: Great! It finally ran! I believe the problem was not enclosing the path in double quotes. That is why it considered "Program" as already after the path. Thank you.

Comment: @Algunillo Pleasure, if you feel that this helped you, please feel free to mark the question as the correct answer.

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar problem when node.js was complaining module does not exist , that is because it lets you save with a file name for eg If statement.js however when you call it in commander it does not like it so try changing the file name and run it and that could fix similar issues

Comment: Hi there, and welcome to SO. Note that this question has an accepted answer already - if you think your answer substantially adds to the question and existing answer, you'll have to spell that out a bit more than you have. Thanks for contributing!